# Using Apache NiFi to write CSV files by contents of column

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have an Apache NiFi flow, where I read in a massive `.csv` file. Here's a sample `.csv`:

```
school, date, city
Vanderbilt, xxxx, xxxx
Georgetown, xxxx, xxxx
Duke, xxxx, xxxx
Vanderbilt, xxxx, xxxx
```

I want to use NiFi to read the file, and then output another `.csv` file by `school` name. I.e. there would be a `.csv` file of two `Vanderbilt` records (two lines total, b/c two records), and one file for `Georgetown`, and one file for `Duke`.

I've used `GetFile` to draw in my file (works, verified), and then `SplitText` (line split count = 1 & header line count = 1), and then `ExtractText`, but I have a very wrong config in that one. Lastly, I have `PutFile`, which writes to where I need it to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at NiFi's record processing capabilities, you will want to use PartitionRecord to partition on the school field, which will produce exactly what you are describing.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html

Comment: I'm actually stiff confused on this. I have to add a property to the config, and then can I ditch `ExtractText`?

Comment: You will to need to setup a CsvReader services and CsvWriter service for PartitionRecord to use, then you need to tell PartitionRecord which field to partition on which is done by adding a property to the processor config like school = /school

Comment: @papelr, For more reference regards to **configuration/usage** of **Partition record processor** take a look into this following link, https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/191760/create-dynamic-partitions-based-on-flowfile-conten.html

Comment: I've looked at the sites.. I can get my info to split by `school`, but I'm having trouble actually writing it anywhere. I go from `GetFile` -> `PartitionRecord` -> `SplitText` -> `ExtractTest` -> `PutFile`,    but this does not seem to work. It writes back to the original file name. My Q is how do I write them to different file names based on `school`

Comment: Before PutFile put an UpdateAttribute and set filename = ${school}  assuming that school is the name of the partition property in PartitionRecord.